# Limit results in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables called users and images. 
Every user have up to 5 pictures.
In a page I show users information plus one image (first uploaded). When I do query like this

```
SELECT
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,
  u.username,
  u.gender,
  u.etc
  .........
  i.picture
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN images i on u.id = i.id
WHERE 
 some_condition
```

and if the user has two uploaded images mysql result is 2 rows. If the images are 3 returned rows are 3 and so on.
How to do so the result to be just one row (one pictue) ?

I tried to add LIMIT 0, 1 but SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS returns the actual number of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do

`select max(i.uploadDate) group by (u.id)`

Comment: which would basically group all user rows into one, and the max(i.uploadDate) should make the row use the details from the last uploaded `use min() for the first`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case when` clause. I'm not a  MySQL person, but you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
  case 
    when SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS > 5 then '5'
    else SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  end,
  u.username,
  u.gender,
  u.etc
  .........
  i.picture
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN images i on u.id = i.id
WHERE 
 some_condition
```

Comment: Thanks, but I`m looking for some more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS will return the number of rows in the full result set, whereas a LIMIT statement tells the query to only return a limited number of rows *from that* result set.

I don't see why you need to use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS at all here, you can just count the number of rows in the last result set (and use a LIMIT).

`$count = mysql_num_rows($result)`